# Laravel exceptions not working at all. It return phpinfo.php in every case

Tags: laravel

Hi guys i'm working with laravel 5.6, i have enabled debugging in .env but still it is not returning any exception and error.
instead of any error or exception it shows a complete page of phpinfo.php

here is an example image what i am actually getting
https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2017/03/inside-the-php-info-section.png

Let me show you my code

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {

    $request->validate([
        'first_name' => 'required|min:3',
        'last_name' => 'required|min:3',
    ]);

    ...
  }
```

the desired output was that if i have not entered any field i.e first_name or last_name it should provide an error that first_name or last_name is required but instead of this it return complete phpinfo.php page

Comment: Can you share your  Routers , functions and form where you submit .

Comment: @MuradShukurlu `Route::post('api/register', 'RegisterController@store');` api/register is route. I test this routes with postman. store function is already show in  question

Comment: Hi @Yasir, can you please confirm that your request is actually reaching to this function. You can use dd() helper in the entry point of the function. sometimes it happen that we have some error in our router so our request goes some where else and we keep on trying checking this function.

Comment: @Raj yes request is reached on controller is any filed is missing or any php syntax error  return phpinfo.php

Answer (score -1):

Although the code sample you have provided does not have any error
I think you should try using the validation like this

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'first_name' => 'required|min:3',
    'last_name' => 'required|min:3',
]);
```

If you still face the error please try commenting you validation code for instance or using a dd() after validation so that we could ensure that the error is in the validation part or somewhere else.